# Drupal 7: Custom 'Node Submit' Page through Views?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I'm a *designer* (read: I know Photoshop) with HTML/CSS skills, and limited PHP skills. I've done some Drupal templates, I've worked with views, panels, etc. So I can't create modules.

Can I still use the Form API (inside views, through rewriting field output for example) to create a custom "Submit Node" page?

If so, how would one accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it requires much coding to achieve that.

To get yourself started in rewriting views output, go to your views page "admin/structure/views/view/VIEW_ID/edit" -> **Advanced** section -> **Theme: Information** at the very bottom of the list.

Display output section: all the template suggestions that can be applied to the whole view (only one template can be applied).

Style output section: any template in this section is applied to every row of the view result.

Row style output section: any template in this section is applied to every field in each row of the view result.

Then you will find template suggestions to every field in the view.

http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/sites/all/modules/views/help/images/style-breakdown-large.png